# iText paragraph limit

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I've to print text to a **PDF** file. This text must not exceed a width, like a textbox where the text wraps. I'm using **[iText](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IText)** with Visual Basic .NET.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`ColumnText`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ColumnText.html) in iText.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ColumText and among others set the width (Java code):

```
ColumnText body_column = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
body_column.setSimpleColumn(1, 50, 569, 800);   /// Java implementation.
```

You should look for VB.net implementation for Columntext.